# bash shell access to $ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable

Tags: windows, bash, git, command

In the bash shell, I'm using git-bash.exe, how do I access the Windows 10 ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable?

If I execute `printenv` I see it in the output with the casing noted but attempts to access it using `echo $ProgramFiles(x86)`, `echo $ProgramFiles\(x86\)` and `echo $"ProgramFiles(x86)"` do not work.

I am able to access the non-x86 version of that environment variable without any issue using `echo $PROGRAMFILES` and do relevant colon removal and backslash to forward replacements necessary to use it in PATH environment variable updates, e.g. `PATH=$PATH:"/${PROGRAMFILES//:\\//} (x86)/Some App Path With Spaces/"` followed by `echo $PATH` and `printenv PATH` that confirms the desired result. The issue is that I'd rather not have to compose the ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable versus being able to use it directly in updates to the PATH environment variable.

Along these same lines when trying to use the Windows APPDATA [ = C:\Users&lt;username>\AppData\Roaming ] environment variable in updates to PATH environment variable I need to be able to replace not only the initial colon & backslash but also the subsequent backslashes with forward slashes.  Using `echo ${APPDATA//:\\//}` produces `C/Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming` and I'm not aware of how to get the bash environment variable character matching and substitution syntax to cover both cases in order to produce the required `C/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming` necessary for use in updates to PATH environment variable.

Comment: Just do `printenv "ProgramFiles(x86)"
`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75982175) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: there's a flaw in the process described below.  In particular, if some environment variable is set to a multi-line value where one of the value lines matches the `sed` expression, you'll capture that line as well.  To avoid this, if you have a Python available, you could use:

```
python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("FOO(BAR)"))'
```

for instance.  This will print `None` if the variable is not set, so you might want to make it fancier: e.g., supply a default value, or use `sys.exit(1)` if the variable is not set, for instance.  (But if you have a Python interpreter available, you might consider writing in Python rather than directly in bash.)

---

Unix shell (sh, bash, etc) variable names—including environment variables—are constrained to character sets that exclude parentheses.  In particular, `"$FOO(BAR)"` *always* parses as a reference to variable `$FOO`, followed by `(BAR)` as a separate word.  This holds even with braceed expansion forms, where the separate word `(BAR)` is syntactically invalid:

```
bash$ echo "${FOO(BAR)}"
bash: ${FOO(BAR)}: bad substitution
```

Nonetheless, it *is* possible to set such variables, and access them, using other programs.  For instance, using Python I *set* `FOO(BAR)` to `hello`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["FOO(BAR)"] = "hello"
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("bash")
bash$
```

This bash instance cannot directly access the variable, but `env` prints all the variables:

```
bash$ env | grep FOO
FOO(BAR)=hello
```

If you have `env` (you probably do) and `sed`, you can combine them to extract arbitrary variables:

```
bash$ setting="$(env | sed -n 's/^FOO(BAR)=//p')"
bash$ echo "$setting"
hello
```

So assuming that Windows Bash doesn't have any special case to work around this particular clumsiness better, this same trick should work for "ProgramFiles(x86)".

#### Substituting multiple backslashes with forward slashes

You're mostly there: the problem is that your pattern looks specifically for `:\` but the strings have multiple `\`s without colons.  Your best bet is probably to have a program or function that actually understands Windows paths, as they don't necessarily have drive letters at the front (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats).  But this pattern works for all-backslash:

```
bash$ v='a\b\c'
bash$ echo ${v//\\/\/}
a/b/c
```

The double slash means "substitute all occurrences".  The *pattern* is then `\\`, which matches one backslash.  The next slash introduces the replacement string, which is `\/`, which means one forward slash.  (This can also be written as just `/` but I find that harder to read, oddly enough.)

Of course this does not replace the colon in `C:`, so we need one more substitution.  You can't do that in one `${...}` expansion, so the trick is to add another one:

```
bash$ v='C:\a\b\c'
bash$ echo ${v//\\/\/}
C:/a/b/c
bash$ v1="${v//\\//}"; echo ${v1/:/}
C/a/b/c
```

Put this inside a shell function, which you can eventually make smart enough to handle all valid paths, and that way you can use `local` to keep the variable name `v1` from leaking.

Comment: Thanks that works.  For $ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable access and conversion to unix path format will use `PFX86="$(env | sed -n 's/^ProgramFiles(x86)=//p')"; PFX86="${PFX86/:\\//}"; echo $PFX86` and for $APPDATA environment variable conversion to unix path format will use `APPDATAX="${APPDATA//\\//}"; APPDATAX="${APPDATAX/:/}"; echo $APPDATAX`

Comment: . . . followed by `PATH=$PATH:"/$PFX86/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Anaconda3_64":"/$PFX86/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Anaconda3_64/Scripts":/$APPDATAX/Python/Python36/Scripts`

Comment: Given that you do apparently have Python (3.6) you might consider using that to do most of the work. Python understands OS-specific path names, using `os.path` for older Python programs or the fancy new [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) introduced in Python 3.4.

Comment: torek - that's a chicken and egg problem as i'm having to get the unix path friendly version of %programfiles(x86)% in order to add my python 3.6.5 environment to my bash shell PATH because I don't operate with python as part of my windows host OS system or user PATH environment settings by default.

Comment: The Python methods basically recreate the functionality of `printenv`, but you could just [use `printenv` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75982175).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding APPDATA: The `cygpath` program can convert pathnames between Windows, Unix and "Mixed" conventions. Both Cygwin and Git for Windows come with this tool. Example:

```
$ echo "$APPDATA"
C:\Users\me\AppDataRoaming\
$ cygpath -u "$APPDATA"
/c/Users/me/AppData/Roaming
$ cygpath -m "$APPDATA"
C:/Users/me/AppData/Roaming
$ cygpath -w "$APPDATA"
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming
```

The "mixed" format is quite usefull because even most windows programs and Git for Windows can handle that format directly.

Assigning the output of `cygpath` to a variable works like this (note the quotes!):

```
$ XAPP=$(cygpath "$APPDATA")
$ echo "$XAPP"
$ cd "$XAPP"
```

Comment: I see that `cygpath $APPDATA` does windows cmd to unix bash path format conversion but how would I use that in the context of an environment variable assignment?   I tried `XAPPPATH="$(cygpath ${APPDATA})"` and `XAPPPATH="$(cygpath $APPDATA)"` and both cases `echo $XPATH` was empty or blank line result.

Comment: Extended answer and `echo "$XAPPPATH"` instead of `$XPATH` should work in your example.

Comment: good catch thanks. I verified `APPDATAX="$(cygpath $APPDATA)"; echo $APPDATAX` produces the desired result. That said it appears git-bash is fine as well with `pushd $APPDATA` processing of windows path format `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming` so it seems the unix path format of it is necessary only when using it to add to PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question almost contains the answer. You just need to do:

```bash
printenv "ProgramFiles(x86)"
```

On my machine, this gives the output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

If you need to assign this to a variable, you can do this via the usual method of [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```bash
progfiles86="$(printenv "ProgramFiles(x86)")"

# It's possible that ProgramFiles(x86) was not set, or it was set to the
# empty string. Do this if you need to distinguish between those two cases:
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    unset progfiles86  # because ProgramFiles(x86) was not set
fi
```

Now you can manipulate `${progfiles86}` as needed. Don't forget to `export` it if you need to access it inside a subprocess.

**If you just wanted the value of the `ProgramFiles(x86)` variable then you can stop reading here.**

---

Command substitution strips trailing newline characters. It's unlikely that the `ProgramFiles(x86)` variable contains any newline characters because it's a file path, and newline characters are not allowed in file paths on Windows, but for a general variable like `FOO(BAR)` it could happen.

To preserve trailing newlines:

```bash
foobar="$(printenv "FOO(BAR)" && echo /)"
foobar="${foobar%$'\n'/}"  # strip extra newline from printenv and '/' from echo
```

This exploits some quirks of the `printenv` command as implemented on GNU systems (including Git Bash on Windows) and BSD systems (including macOS):

- If `FOO(BAR)` is set to any value, including the empty string, then `printenv` prints that value followed by a single trailing newline, and exits normally. (So if `FOO(BAR)` is empty, `printenv` prints a single newline.)
- If `FOO(BAR)` is not set, `printenv` prints nothing at all, and exits with non-zero status.

Hence, if you need to distinguish empty `FOO(BAR)` from unset `FOO(BAR)`:

```bash
foobar="$(printenv "FOO(BAR)" && echo /)"

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    foobar="${foobar%$'\n'/}"  # strip extra newline from printenv and '/' from echo
else
    unset foobar  # because FOO(BAR) was not set
fi
```

Remember that `$?` can only be used to access the exit status of the command immediately prior to it.